# EC2 credits - t2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

we usually use t2 instances in order to host our application.
Sometimes we have the next situation:
An EC2 instance is consuming more than baseline CPU, so a couple of hour later this instance consumed all the credit and it starts working at 20% of CPU and the application gets very slow.
So we have to start more EC2 instance manually or terminate that instance.

We would like to receive some recommendation to manage the auto scalling instances and do it in the correct way. We dont think the best solution is terminate and start again EC2 instances manually.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. You should not be terminating instances just because you have consumed the T2 credits.

The T2 family is ideal for bursty utilization, where CPU is not used heavily for continued periods. Good use-cases are dev/test systems, lightly used systems and jump boxes.

Your first option is to **use a different instance family**. Since your system seems to consume more CPU than is offered by the T2 family, select an instance type such as M4. This does not have the 'credit' concept.

Alternatively, there is a **T2 Unlimited** option that will allow T2 instances to use additional CPU. However, there is a charge associated with it, based on average utilization.

See: [Unlimited Mode for Burstable Performance Instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html)

Answer (score 0):

- T2 is most easy option to implement right now.
- You can also create a T2 instance and load balance between the two instances
- If your application is about most reads and less writes then get a cloudfront 
  distribution

Answer (score 0):

If you are often depleting your credit balance, you should be using a larger instance or a different class of instance.

If it's a very rare occurrence, `t2.unlimited` may be worth considering.

In any case, it's a good practice to have an alarm on credit balance influence your scaling. I also use an alarm to remove the instance from the load balancer when the credits are depleted entirely. You will regenerate credits over time as long as you are not surpassing the baseline performance for your instance.